# Multi-Application Server Environment and Memcached Security

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, coldfusion, memcached

We are looking to integrate Memcached into our infrastructure, but have a security concern before we do. We run several platforms including ASP.NET and ColdFusion and have many app developers working many little applications across the different platforms. The concern is this:

App A places item "dog" into cache.

App B reads item "dog" (or worse: App B updates item "dog")

After this happens, App A either retrieves bad information, or has already had its information viewed, aka "stolen". What we would like to do is make it so that each app can only interact with its own sandbox, and may not interfere with or read other application's data.

Is this possible? Thanks.

Comment: When a particular app accesses the cache, prepend an application-specific identifier to the identifier the application wants to use.

Comment: Does memcached work with partial identifiers? For example, if I had the keys dog_Name and dog_SSN, could I query it for "d*" and get every key that starts with a "d"? Or do keys need to match exactly?

Comment: Memcached is very simple, it does not support regular expressions and it not a general purpose database. It is a distributed dictionary -- you ask it for an exact key you want to retrieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create multiple memcached instances on your infrastructure and give each instance a different port. In this way you isolate yourself -- however this is not the way you want to do things, you will have to split your available memory resources.

---

You should be able to use "convention" to your advantage -- i.e.,e use Anon's suggestion.

My advice is: anything that needs to be protected should not be in a memcached instance. Use this with anon's advice and your doing what is considered best practise.

Comment: I had this idea as well, and thought that our server admins may hate us for it. It's good to hear similar ideas though. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

memcached is very explictly leaving out security from its deployment (no access control lists, no cache content tampering protection, no traffic privacy etc), all in the name of performance. Access control (SASL) can optionally be compiled into memcached, but most times is left out.

If you need tampering proof of content, or privacy of items in cache you have to implement it in the app (ie. sign or encrypt the cached content before uploading it), but you'll pay the cost of signing/veryfing the signature and/or encrypting/decrypting with each cache access, and you also have a fairly complicated problem of provisioning the keys needed to do these operations.

Answer (score 0):

The last few versions we've shipped with SASL auth to prevent unauthorized access in untrusted environments.

In development trees, we have pluggable storage engine support allowing you to do fun things like isolate caches between apps.  e.g., I have a deployed instance with many users who can't see each other's data.  User1 can cache `dog` and User2 can cache `dog` and they do not interfere.